# How to turn a tf tensor to some form that keras can fit?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm using keras to build a network, however, I have to declare a tf tensor to do some cuda computation in `set_abstraction_msg` and `set_abstraction` methods, and then turn the tensor back to some kinds of form that keras can complie and fit. How can I do that?

The method below is generally called `getModel`, but I called it `pointnet2` instead.

The code below is mainly to, first declare the tensorflow placeholder, second do some cuda computation and apply `Conv2D` and `BatchNormalization` in `set_abstraction_msg` and `set_abstraction` methods, third apply some `Dense`, `BatchNormalization` and `Dropout` ops.

```py
def pointnet2(nb_classes):
    input_points = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(16, 1024, 3))
    model_input = Input(tensor=input_points)

    sa1_xyz, sa1_points = set_abstraction_msg(model_input,
                                              None,
                                              512,
                                              [0.1, 0.2, 0.4],
                                              [16, 32, 128],
                                              [[32, 32, 64], [64, 64, 128], [64, 96, 128]])

    sa2_xyz, sa2_points = set_abstraction_msg(sa1_xyz,
                                              sa1_points,
                                              128,
                                              [0.2, 0.4, 0.8],
                                              [32, 64, 128],
                                              [[64, 64, 128], [128, 128, 256], [128, 128, 256]])

    sa3_xyz, sa3_points = set_abstraction(sa2_xyz,
                                          sa2_points,
                                          [256, 512, 1024])

    # point_net_cls
    c = Dense(512, activation='relu')(sa3_points)
    c = BatchNormalization()(c)
    c = Dropout(0.5)(c)
    c = Dense(256, activation='relu')(c)
    c = BatchNormalization()(c)
    c = Dropout(0.5)(c)
    c = Dense(nb_classes, activation='softmax')(c)
    prediction = Flatten()(c)

    model = Model(inputs=model_input, outputs=prediction)

    # turn tf tensor to keras
    return model
```

I tried `Input(tensor=input_points)`. It turned out that `prediction` is a tensor, which is prefect for me. But I want tensor turned to keras form in the end, and above code got some error like this at this line `Model(inputs=model_input, outputs=prediction)`:

```
Output tensors to a Model must be the output of a TensorFlow Layer (thus holding past layer metadata). Found: Tensor("flatten/Reshape:0", shape=(16, 40), dtype=float32)
```

For more information, the complete code project is here: https://github.com/HarborZeng/pointnet2-keras

Comment: You should include the code of what you actually tried, not just some random error messages.

Comment: have you tried creating a custom keras layer https://keras.io/layers/writing-your-own-keras-layers/ ?

Comment: @nickthefreak I have not tried that way, because I don't know how. Do you happen to have an example or demo?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I have updated the question content , please have a look.

Comment: So I guess these set_abstraction function calls do the CUDA computations? How are these implemented? They need to use tensorflow operations for this, there is no way around back. This is in order to compute gradients thorugh these operations.